# Google chrome url capturing code consumes high CPU utilization

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ui-automation

I am using following code to extract the current tab url from Google chrome, but it consumes huge CPU(10-15%) while capturing the url. Below is my code, I want to optimize the following code.

```
public static string GetChromeUrl(Process process)
        {
            try
            {
                if (process == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("process");
                if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return null;
                AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
                if (element == null)
                    return null;
                AutomationElement edit = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
                     new AndCondition(
                          new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "address and search bar", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase),
                          new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)));
                if (edit != null)
                {
                    var i = ((ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
                    return i;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you can get a spike, but it lasts just a moment. It's even somewhat *worse* if you use the *proper* `var element = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, [And Condition])`. Unless you mean you're using this code in a loop, for some reason.

Comment: With *proper*, I mean without using the Process class to find the main Window.